# How to slice a period of time in 24hrs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-time

I am using java.util.date
for example,
I have two time slot : 10:00:00 - 11:00:00,13:30:00-14:30:00

I want to remove these time slots from 24hrs and get the remaining timings?

Comment: show an example of what you want to acheive

Comment: @k-wasilewski  it is for the appointment schedule. let say user1 has a meeting from 10Am-11AM and 14PM-15PM . i want to get remaining timeslots of user1 which are available to schedule another meeting.

Comment: Is this just time-of-day, for any day but not a specific date?

Comment: @BasilBourque it for a given date. when we input a date then we need to get available timeslots of that user

Comment: There are still many unknowns, but it could go like this: add 24 timeslots to a List, parse reserved timeslots to get the format of your list's elements, remove those parsed timeslots from the list, parse back your list's elements to the desired format. It's all about parsing back and forth from/to java.util.date, so read about that..

Comment: @k-wasilewski Ok i will try

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `java.util.Date`. That class is one of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.  These legacy classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `LocalTime`

If you are working with time-of-day in general, and not for a specific date, use `LocalTime` class.

```
LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 )
```

Make a class to define a time range. The *ThreeTen-Extra* library has such range classes for a pair of `Instant` objects, and for a pair of `LocalDateTime` objects. But unfortunately no class for pair of `LocalTime`.

In Java 16 and later, we can use a record. Or define a conventional class.

```
public record LocalTimeRange ( LocalTime start , LocalTime end ) ;
```

Set up your inputs, sorted from earlier to later.

```java
List< LocalTimeRange > inputs = List.of(
    new LocalTimeRange ( LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 ) , LocalTime.of( 11 , 0 ) ) ,
    new LocalTimeRange ( LocalTime.of( 13 , 30 ) , LocalTime.of( 14 , 30 ) ) 
);
```

Create time range objects.

For a generic 24-hour day, we can start with `LocalTime.MIN`. Make a range from that minimum to the start of your first input range. Next range is from the end of your first input to the start of the successive input. Lather, rinse, repeat. On the last input, use `LocalTime.MIN` or `MAX` for the end, depending on your needs.

Notice that we are defining our spans of time using the Half-Open approach where the start is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This allows for spans to neatly abut without gaps.

To apply these to a date (`LocalDate`), specify a time zone (`ZoneId`) to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object. But understand that not all time-of-day values exist on certain dates in certain zones. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean that days can vary in length, such as being 23 or 23.5 or 25 hours long. Some time-of-day values may be repeated or may not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Basil Bourque. I will try

Comment: Very good suggestions! You can include a note about [`List#removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) which the OP can use to remove `inputs` from the list of `LocalTimeRange` objects where `inputs`  contains the list of `LocalTimeRange` to be removed.